# First time File.Copy operation is slow on AWS EC2 Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

On Amazon (AWS) EC2 Windows Server 2008

This line of C# code

```
File.Copy(file1, file2);
```

is executed first time about a minute, when repeated - in no time
Any ideas?